# How to save GVIM settings?

Tags: vim

I just installed `GVIM`, went through the menus, and changed a bunch of settings.

I closed `GVIM`, and the settings were all lost. :(

I made my changes again.

Now how do I keep my settings?

Comment: I don't think this is off topic.  It's about a tool commonly used by programmers.

It has a simple answer:   Use :mkvimrc to create a vimrc file  (see also :mkview and :mksession)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `:set` command to list all settings and put it to `${HOME}/.vimrc`.

```
:se[t]     Show all options that differ from their default value.
```

Comment: +1 doesn't mention the GUI but useful answer anyway, thanks. :)

Comment: btw: I'd more be interested in how to save the settings that I have currently applied into a file, rather than starting with a `.vimrc` from scratch. Would be awesome if you could edit that into your answer, as I think it should be possible to somehow redirect the output of `:set` this way.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why nobody mentioned to use a vim session to save global settings and the views for all windows. Of course mastering `.vimrc` should be on the agenda of any serious vim user, but sessions can help further. Especially since they are similar to 'profiles' which are familiar to many people.

There also exist a plugin for gvim that facilitates the dealing with sessions further ([sessions.vim : Easy session management for gvim.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2151)

Comment: I just tested this and my color and syntax highlighting settings where not saved into the session I saved from the GUI. When I opened the saved session only the file reopened, the settings were lost.