# How to save GVim preferred color scheme?

Tags: vim, configuration, persistence

One topic about this is closed at the time I opened this new topic:
[How to save GVIM settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661988/how-to-save-gvim-settings)

Comment: OP wants to give related answer for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661988/how-to-save-gvim-settings  Hence has written this question.

Comment: You can ask vi/vim specific questions here. http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When someone searchs for this specific question, google do NOT send you to vi.stackexchange.com but to stackoverflow, to that closed topic.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your vimrc file (.vimrc or _vimrc). Change "yourcolor" for an existing real color name, ex: darkblue, etc

```
if has('gui_running') 
   colorscheme yourcolor
endif
```

Comment: No. 1. That's not how it works. 2. You don't even explain what or where `.vimrc` and `_vimrc` are.

Comment: 1- it works. 2-You are demanding. 3- People can find them with little effort.